# Build error when trying to build the java portion of my project

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, ringojs

After cloning the ringojs repository, i run in the directory:

```
ant jar
```

However, the build is failed with around 100 errors, here is some of them:

```
    init:

    compile:
        [javac] Compiling 55 source files to /Users/ZConsulting/repos/ringojs/build/classes
        [javac] repos/ringojs/src/org/ringojs/engine/Callback.java:19: error: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
        [javac] import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
        [javac]                              ^
        [javac] repos/ringojs/src/org/ringojs/engine/Callback.java:20: error: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
        [javac] import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
        [javac]                              ^
        [javac] repos/ringojs/src/org/ringojs/engine/Callback.java:21: error: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
        [javac] import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
        [javac]                              ^
        [javac] repos/ringojs/src/org/ringojs/engine/Callback.java:22: error: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
        [javac] import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;
        [javac]                              ^
        [javac] repos/ringojs/src/org/ringojs/engine/RhinoEngine.java:19: error: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
        [javac] import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
        [javac]                              ^

BUILD FAILED
repos/ringojs/build.xml:76: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

My context is building back end application on googleappengine for my project.

Comment: You're missing the rhino jar file in your classpath.

Comment: isn't supposed to be part of the repository when i cloned it from github?

Comment: I don't know. Add the owner of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You will need apache ant and ivy installed.
Ivy should download the rhino jar.

If ivy and ant are insalled do a

```
ant update
ant jar
```

This should help.